# Angular 2 custom function not getting called from razorpay options property

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms, razorpay

I have an options property which has handler function.
And i want to call a custom method from this property, but the method doesnt not seem to be called.

Basically im trying to create a new order in the checkOutorder() which should get created on successful payment

**component.ts**

```
options = {
  //Redirect on success order
  if (typeof response.razorpay_payment_id == "undefined" ||response.razorpay_payment_id < 1) 
  {
    console.log("failure page");
  } else
  {
    console.log("success page");
   /*How to call the checkOutorder function from this property*/
    this.checkOutorder   //Doesnt call !
 },
};


checkOutorder() {
    ...
    ...
  console.log('Order Placed SuccessFully')
}

 public initPay(): void {
    this.options.amount = this.getTotal() * 100;
    this.rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.options);
    /* If i put the contents of checkOutorder() here, it works , but "Order Placed SuccessFully" message appears even before the payment is made*/
    this.rzp1.open();
}
```

**component.html**

```
<button id="rzp-button1" class="razorpay-payment-button" (click)="initPay();">Pay</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you don't write if-else block inside JS object.

You may try something like below,

```
options = {
   handler: function(response) {
     // Control comes here only in case of success. In case of failure,  razorpay form shows "Retry button"
     console.log('Payment Success');
     // Your custom logic
   }
}
```

For further info on handler function, please refer sample code [here](https://codepen.io/Mayur-Wadpalliwar/pen/eVNNVV):

Comment: Please give an answer on what is the way to call checkOutorder()...The link u specified in in Angular1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"handler": function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      this.callbackRazor(response) // your function
    }.bind(this),
```